# best practice for using same xml layout or use single one in fragment listview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have a project HomePage with 4 ListFragments,
i create also 4 xml layouts of the listfragments,
there layout is the same so
if the same should i use only 1 layout for 4 ListFragments?

is it a good performance practice using 1 xml layout with listView
on 4 ListFragments Clases? each Fragments class there deference only
is from sortOrder in Cursor, so its ok to use only 1 xml to enhance or to less implementation of other objects or less ccreating xml can make or enhance the performance speed?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to reuse a layout when possibility because it allows you share as much XML as possible within your application.

Each layout file that you create needs to be added to your resulting APK. You can see that by reusing layout files, you can save the amount of layout files that end up in the APK.

However, there is no performance impact. Your code would not run faster if you were to re-use layouts.

You can get some more information on how to reuse layouts here: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/.